# Need to Fetch logs from cloudwatch to aws Lambda each day and process them(Scheduled event)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there a possible way to fetch all the logs from that particular day and process them using lambda? This needs to happen once a day on a scheduled basis so that I can filter data from logs and process them and send an SNS notification

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get your cloud watch metrics from specific day with boto3 with python you will need to use put_metric_data. Take a look at the documentation https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_data